# Alignment of the image is changing?

Tags: html, css

I was working on the website,where in the hero-container I placed images on right side,In that one of the image's alignment is conpletely changing during the zoom-in and zoom-out of the web page,I have this proble with the image with class name"action-bg suprised-girl" inside grid-stretch background div.

How to solve this to place the image  without moving it's position while zoom-in and zoom-out?

```css
/* welcome-text */

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 740px;
  padding: 20vh;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 1920px;
  justify-content: start;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.primary-actions-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 32px;
  width: fit-content;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}

.welcome-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 8px;
}

.welcome-text h3 {
  font: 24px/1 Poppins;
  color: #d72f2f;
}

.welcome-text h3 span {
  color: #000e14;
}

.welcome-text h1 {
  font: 600 48px/1 Poppins;
  color: #d72f2f;
}


/* btn-group */

.btn-group {
  display: flex;
  gap: 8px;
}

.btn-group .btn {
  height: 54px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background-color: #fff;
  min-width: 120px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #000e14;
  font-size: 14px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border: 0;
}

.btn-group .btn.active {
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: rgba(215, 47, 47, 0.2);
  color: #d72f2f;
}

.btn.active:hover {
  border: none;
}


/* search-large */

.search-large {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ff9c9c;
  border-radius: 24px;
  gap: 8px;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 16px;
  width: fit-content;
}

.btn.btn-primary.no-glow {
  text-shadow: none;
}

.search-large .large-search {
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.search-large .large-search:placeholder-shown {
  color: #f38383;
}

.wrapper .background {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper .background .markers-map {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -200px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.wrapper .background .action-bg {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  bottom: -50px;
  right: calc(50% - 600px);
}

.wrapper .background .circle-1 {
  width: 640px;
  height: 640px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 30%;
  background-color: #d72f2f;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.wrapper .background .circle-2 {
  width: 640px;
  height: 640px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 60%;
  top: 20%;
  background-color: rgba(215, 47, 47, 0.2);
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.action-link {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: #486bf5;
  gap: 8px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="topbar">
    <div class="topbar-container">
      <div class="topbar-logo">
        <a href="#" class="logo-link">
          <img src="img/logoWhite.svg" alt="1sqft logo" title="1SQFT" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="toggle-icon" id="toggle-icon">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </div>

      <div class="topbar-actions">

        <div class="quick-info" id="token-count">
          <span class="label">Tokens:</span>
          <span class="value">104</span>
        </div>
        <div class="quick-info outlined" id="wallet-balance">
          <span class="label label-icon">
            <img src="img/wallet-1.svg" class="wallet"alt="wallet icon" title="wallet" />
            Wallet: ₹</span>
          <span class="value">1,00,403</span>
        </div>
        <span class="divider"></span>
        <div class="action-group">
          <button class="btn btn-small icon-btn">
            <span class="has-notifications"></span>
            <img src="img/Quickaction.svg" alt="bid notifications" title="bid notifications" /> </button>
          <button class="btn btn-small icon-btn">
            <span class="has-notifications"></span>
            <img src="img/Quickaction-1.svg" alt="general notifications" title="general notifications" /> </button>
        </div>
        <span class="divider"></span>
        <button class="btn btn-small icon-btn"><img src="img/Quickaction-2.svg" alt="profile" title="profile" />
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <main>

    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="grid-stretch background">
        <span class="circle-1"></span>
        <span class="circle-2"></span>
        <img src="img/suprised-girl.png" alt="suprised-girl" class="action-bg suprised-girl">
        <img src="img/map-bg.svg" alt="1sqft markers-map" class="markers-map">
      </div>
      <div class="primary-actions-container">
        <div class="welcome-text">
          <h3><span>Hello,</span> John Smith ! </h3>
          <h1>Let’s buy tokens</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button class="btn btn-primary active">
            Buy
          </button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary">
            Sell
          </button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary">
            Bid
          </button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary">
            Market
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="search-large-container">
          <div class="search-large">
            <img src="img/search.svg" alt="search" title="search" />
            <input type="text" class="large-search" placeholder="Place, Price or Property" />
            <button class="btn btn-primary no-glow">Make a search</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="action-link" title="location">
          <img src="img/needle.svg" alt="location needle icon" /> </button>
          Chennai</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```